# How to monitor all container status in kubernetes?

Tags: containers, kubernetes, monitor

At present, there are lots of containers running in kubernetes cluster, is there any good solution to monitor each container and could sent alert when container is in bad status ?

Answer (score 1):

This is broad subject and a lot depends on what you actually want to monitor, the size of your deployment and the technical expertise available.

The most comprehensive solution is [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io). It comes with extensive documentation, getting start guide, etc. The setup is pretty involved though.

Depending on how you have setup your cluster [Grafana](http://grafana.org) might already be available. If not, you will need to deploy these addons: [Heapster, InfluxDB and Grafana](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb). There are a number of tutorials but again it depends much on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

agree with Janos. i use the grafana, heapster, influx.

ill add that you need to rethink you monitoring and should focus on monitoring the service that the containers make up vs just the containers themselves.

Here is some other material that may help with understanding that:

- https://medium.com/intel-sdi/monitor-the-systems-you-love-on-kubernetes-6dcb256bd63c#.y233qif07
- https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-kubernetes-era/

good luck